# How do I apply git patch programmatically?

Tags: git

Is there a way to do `git add -e` in more programmatic way?  There is `git update-index` but it doesn't do patches like I want to do. I could set `core.editor` to something but I rather not to depends on 3rd party application that users may or may not have.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could create a patch from the diff using `git diff > my.patch`, modify that patch, and then apply it?

Comment: Can you explain the use case? Also, as @jthill points out, no other users will be using your repository, so there are no dependency concerns.

Answer (score 1):

> I could set core.editor to something but I rather not to depends on 3rd party application that users may or may not have.

You can set that for yourself because your repo is yours. You can't set that for anybody else because theirs is theirs.

Answer (score 0):

Try `git add -p` (patch) with your editor set to something in the terminal (like Vim).

With this command, you can see and edit each patch, one by one. The advantage of `git add -p` over `git add -e` is that it doesn't assume you want to edit every patch. Unless you need to edit every single change you make after the fact, I'd recommend `git add -p`.

Comment: The question was how to use them programmatically. Patch is an interactive command